# How to make "Time" part of a date field not required?

Tags: 7, datetime

Using the [Date module](http://drupal.org/project/date), how would one make the Time part of a date field not required when the whole field is set to "Required".

Also if possible, not display the Time on the front end when there's no time specified?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible without some re-engineering of how the date module works, or at least writing your own custom date field.

The [`date_field_validate()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/date_field_validate/7) function calls [`DateObject::validGranularity()`](http://api.drupalize.me/api/drupal/function/DateObject%3A%3AvalidGranularity/7) which checks to make sure there are sufficient date parts for the granularity you've chosen. If the field instance is set to be required, it's necessary for that check to pass before you can save the field values. Obviously this check won't pass if you haven't provided all of the relevant date parts.

A simple way around the problem might be to use a field collection, to which you can add two fields: one for the date and one for the time. There is a [Timefield](http://drupal.org/project/timefield) module out there, I recommend the dev version as the alpha version has some weird problems.

That method would also help with your display issue as the date and time are now separate fields.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I suppose I could just also add a new  checkbox field labelled "Hide time", and do some frontend stuff to check the value of this checkbox, and use a different date formatter (that doesn't output time) depending whether it's checked or not. I guess [`hook_field_attach_view_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_attach_view_alter/7) is a good way to achieve this.

Comment: Yeah it's not ideal but you'll have to code/configure your way around the built-in 'limitation'; the method you've mentioned would be perfect, I'm sure there are other ways too depending on how creative you want to get :)

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible but it might be in the future though it's a long standing [feature request](https://drupal.org/node/259308). Besides the mentioned [timefield](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/40704/how-to-make-time-part-of-a-date-field-not-required) you could use a [select field wich has been described here](http://www.capellic.com/blog/required-date) or [CCK Time](https://drupal.org/project/cck_time).

Comment: In the drupal.org issue you linked, the "Partial Date" module is mentioned. I just tried it but it's outdated and it looks awful. The "timefield" and "cck time" modules are outdated too.